# How to keep error messages on screen with syslinux

Tags: linux, boot, boot-loader, bootable, syslinux

I am making the assumption that I'm using syslinux because I have a syslinux.cfg file present on my USB boot disk.

The configuration of syslinux is the following:

```
UI /linux/boot/vesamenu.c32

TIMEOUT 140
MENU ROWS 4

MENU CLEAR
MENU BACKGROUND /linux/boot/bootlogo.png

LABEL default
MENU LABEL Run Linux
KERNEL /linux/boot/vmlinuz
APPEND vga=769 initrd=/linux/boot/initrfs.img load_ramdisk=1 prompt_ramdisk=0 rw printk.time=0 apparmor=0 perch

LABEL default
MENU LABEL Run Linux debug
KERNEL /linux/boot/vmlinuz
APPEND vga=769 initrd=/linux/boot/initrfs.img load_ramdisk=1 prompt_ramdisk=0 rw printk.time=0 apparmor=0 debug perch
```

The machine does not boot as expected. I can see the menu and choose options.

However, the error message is only shown for a couple of milliseconds and the the meanu re-appears.

Is there a way to configure syslinux not to display the menu again but to stay on the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need to add a TOTALTIMEOUT value, like so:

```
# boot after 30 seconds.
TOTALTIMEOUT 300
```